# BPMN in WSO2 ESB

Tags: workflow, wso2, bpel, bpmn

I want to use BPMN in WSO2 ESB, but unfortunately it seems that WSO2 ESB does not support BPMN and only support BPEL. Is there any way to integrate a BPMN engine such as activiti or jBPM or something else with WSO2 ESB?

Comment: You can use BPS ...But still BPMN support is not there, it is in the roadmap. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BPS300/WSO2+Business+Process+Server+Documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at Intalio|bpms.
It is creating a valid bpel process from a BPMN diagram.

Answer (score 1):

You could integrate Engines like Activiti, Camunda or jBPM using the built-in REST-APIs. For example, take a look at the Activiti REST-API: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_rest_api